# BigCommerce app to add a JS snippet once installed

Tags: bigcommerce

Is it possible to use BigCommerce API to add a JS snippet to a store's website once an app is installed?

I have looked at the theme API but I think that is more tailored for a developer looking to create a full-blown theme for BigCommerce.

So the flow of the app should look something like:
- Install app
- Account automatically created for user
- HTML/JS Snippet automatically loaded on store's web site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would only be possible to feed this in through a banner via the API (documentation isn't live yet). Unfortunately, banners are only configured/available to 4 different page types and not the whole store.

When doing an app install process, prompt the merchant/user to place the script in footer.html along side steps on how to locate this section. Alternatively, they can add it to the web analytics page within the control panel. This would not require they view HTML/CSS. This is currently what app partners do to solve for this.

One app that I know of will feed in some content through webdav, but it still requires that the merchant/user create a user account that has webdav access, communicate those credentials to the app, and then add a line to template file(s). You would be at risk automatically trying to add that line to template files due to them being possibly customized.

Comment: Is this API accessible already? Would it be possible to see a summary of what this API looks like?

Comment: It is API accessible already. You can get a rough approximation of the changes from the Ruby API client my updates were merged earlier this week.